# MS Access database (2010) how to create temporary table/procedure/view from Query Designer

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

Is there any way how to create temporary table/view/stored procedure in MS Access database (2010) using Query Designer?

Whenever i try to execute something like this:

```
SELECT * INTO #temp_table
FROM (SELECT column_1, column_2 FROM table)
```

MS Access throws an error:

> Syntax error in CREATE TABLE statement.

With no further information.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Access SQL does not support executing more than one SQL statement at a time, so the notion of a #temp table does not really apply. If you require a temporary table then you need to

- create a "real" table,
- do your work with it, and then
- delete (drop) the table when you're done.

Answer (score 5):

While this has been answered for a year, I hope the following approach might be helpful to others who are, like me, trying to compensate for MS Access shortcomings in a pragmatic way and want to focus on the actual sql-queries.

**It covers:**

- running easy to read sql-procedures stored in textfiles (the common solution of coding them in VBA with concatenated strings becomes unhandy and difficult rather soon)
- using "temporary" tables. Note that this solution does not prevent accdbs from "bloating up" - so they still have to be compressed from time to time. This can be prevented if you chose to run your procedure in a temporary database, which requires some additional coding and error-handling.

(I use an empty accdb with the following code as templates and then work from there, e.g. if additional VBA-Routines or Forms are required.)

**Steps:**

1 - Store your SQL-statement or whole procedures in a txtfile.
In an attempt to keep the VBA-code short it requires

- sql statements to be closed with a semicolon ; followed by a linebreak
- commented lines to span the whole line, meaning no additional inline characters before the /* and or after the */

The OP obv. has access to an sql-editor, others might not. But: even in a company environment you should usually be able to get your hands on some freeware texteditor with SQL-highlighting (like [notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/) which highlights syntax in files with .sql-extensions).

2 - Calling the routine

```
Sub SubRunSQL()
On Error Resume Next
droptemptables
On Error GoTo 0

runSQL CurrentProject.path & "\_sql\p01.sql"

End Sub
```

3 - Closing + deleting the "temporary" Tables (in my case labeled with a prefix "tmp", bc Access has issues with the # character in table names - namely: tablename has to be put in [brackets] in the sql, which results in issues when deleting those tables in a loop).

Wrapping it in "resume next" is everything but elegant, but in my case it proved the most robust solution (the goal being the coding of the actual SQL-Code, not some UI around it.)

```
Sub droptemptables()
Dim tdf As TableDef
For Each tdf In CurrentDb.TableDefs
    If tdf.Name Like "tmp*" Then
        DoCmd.Close acTable, tdf.Name, acSaveNo
        DoCmd.DeleteObject acTable, tdf.Name
    End If
Next tdf
End Sub
```

4 - fetching the SQL-Procedure and processing the single statements in a loop.

```
Sub runSQL(path As String)

Dim dbs As DAO.Database
Set dbs = CurrentDb

Dim sql As String
sql = fetchSQL(path)

' optional: replace some string in your textfile with a public declared variable (here: Public Const dwh As String = "'I:\mydwh.accdb'")
sql = Replace(sql, "#dwh", dwh)

' Split at semicolon + carriage left
Dim arrsql() As String
arrsql() = Split(sql, ";" & vbNewLine)

' Loop through the SQL-Statements
Dim i As Integer
For i = LBound(arrsql()) To UBound(arrsql())
    Debug.Print arrsql(i)
    dbs.Execute arrsql(i), dbFailOnError
Next i
End Sub
```

5 - A standard function for returning the contents of a textfile as string.
In this case, i also skip commented lines, which is redundant if you chose not to comment your sql.

```
Function fetchSQL(path As String) As String

Dim skpLine As Boolean
Dim Line As String
Dim iFile As Integer
iFile = FreeFile
Open path For Input As #iFile

' skip commented lines /* ... */
Do Until EOF(iFile)
    Line Input #iFile, Line
    If Left(Line, 2) = "/*" Then skpLine = True
    If skpLine = False Then fetchSQL = fetchSQL & vbNewLine & Line
    If Right(Line, 2) = "*/" Then skpLine = False
Loop
Close #iFile
End Function
```

Comment: an alternative approach that requires some more VBA might be to use csv files (+auto genereated schema.ini files) as temporary tables - performance might be superslow with larger files, but it prevents the accdb from bloating

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no way to execute a SQL statement like the one in your question in the Access Query Designer, as it expects every statement to be a View/Procedure or Function definition.

There is a general problem with you statement. When using a subselect/derived table within your FROM clause, you will have to use an alias for the returned results. This will work in SQL Server Management Studio:

```
SELECT * INTO #temp_table
FROM (SELECT column_1, column_2 FROM table) AS someAlias
```

I recommend using SQL Server Management Studio (or a similar tool) for most of the SQL work when developing Access Data Project (ADP) applications.

Comment: *"I recommend using SQL Server Management Studio ... for most of the SQL work when developing Access applications."* - That is bad advice. There are significant differences between Access SQL and T-SQL so a query that will work in SSMS will not necessarily work in Access.

Comment: @Gord: Thanks for that hint. Based on the context of views+stored procedures I was assuming an Access Data Project. I clarified my recommendation in that regard.

Comment: Question itself is abou Access SQL and not about T-SQL. I know how to acomplish things i need in T-SQL, but i am trying to figure out how to make them work in Access Sql

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT*
INTO Temp1
FROM TableName;
```

**Note:** you should have an existing table from which you want to create your temporary table.

Use a SELECT statement to check your results:

```
SELECT*
FROM Temp1;
```

Answer (score -1):

This will work if you add:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
SELECT * INTO #temp_table
FROM (SELECT column_1, column_2 FROM table)
```

Comment: But MS Access does not allow multiple Select Statement