# How do I find unmatched records with a table that contains comma separated values

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to check if the values from `Table1` exist in `Table2`.
The thing is that the values are comma separated in `Table1`

**Table 1**

| ID | TXT |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 129(a),P24 |
| 2 | P112 |
| 3 | P24,XX |
| 4 | 135(a),135(b) |

**Table 2**

| ID |
| --- |
| P24 |
| P112 |
| P129(a) |
| 135(a) |
| 135(b) |

The following only works if the complete cell value exists in both tables:

```
SELECT Table1.ID, Table1.TXT
FROM Table1 LEFT JOIN Table2 ON Table1.[TXT] = Table2.[ID]
WHERE (((Table2.ID) Is Null));
```

**MY QUESTION IS:**
Is there a way to check each comma separated value and return those that do not exists in `Table 2`.
In above example the value `XX` should end up in the result.

Comment: Is this really a comma separated string and not a multi-value field? Data samples should be provided as text tables or CREATE and INSERT action SQL, not images.

Comment: If this is CSV and not multi-value field, I expect will need a VBA custom function.

Comment: it's a short text field with values separated by comma's

Comment: Storing values as comma delimited lists is a bad design from a performance and data integrity standpoint. Storing the individual values as separate rows, instead of as a list would save a lot of future headaches.  `the value XX should end up in the result.` Why? I'd expect to see `3P129(a)` because that value is not contained in any of the TXT lists.

Comment: `3P129(a)` was indeed incorrect. I edited my post. Value `XX` is not in Table 2.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you store your data in that way (which is bad practice as sos mentioned above), but you need to mimic the temp table like in SQL server.

1. Select from table1 and create different txt rows per id.
2. Insert the results from section 1 into the  table3.
3. Select from table3 and join it to table2.
4. Delete table 3.

**Table3 the temp table**

| ID | TXT |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 129(a) |
| 1 | P24 |
| 2 | P112 |
| 3 | P24 |
| 3 | XX |
| 4 | 135(a) |
| 4 | 135(b) |

Here is some explanation [MS Access database (2010) how to create temporary table/procedure/view from Query Designer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29698198/ms-access-database-2010-how-to-create-temporary-table-procedure-view-from-quer)